# sails js socket events does not triggered after server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I have a model User stored in Mongo (also user sessions stored in redis). For example, users has such ids - user_1 and user_2. The user_1 send from client side message

```
socket.post('/user/move', {value: "some_value"}, function(res) {
        log('on move message: ', res);
    });
```

Controller of "move" is

```
move: function(req, res, next) {
   var value = req.param('value');
   User.message("user_2", {from: "user_1", value: value});
}
```

it works user_2 got the message. But if i'm restart a sails server and try to send (make socket post) the same event do not delivered.

Comment: If the browser page was also not refreshed, then the socket on the client would not have been reopened.

Comment: Thanx! You are right, but why i got a socket.on('connect') message without refreshing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. After server restart we neen do this

```
socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {
    socket.get('/user');
}
```

this is will subscribe user to model User events.